# Using LINQ to get distinct items that do not join

Tags: linq

I'm having problems running a LINQ query between two tables and returning an answer set that doesen't match.

```
TB_AvailableProducts
-Prod_ID
-Name
....
TB_Purchases
-Cust_ID
-Prod_ID
```

Is there a way to get all distinct products that a customer has not purchased by using 1 LINQ query, or do I have to be doing two separate queries, 1 for all products and 1 for purchased products, and compare the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307353/linq-many-to-many-left-join-grouping

Comment: @Jani Thanks, but it looks like that is selecting a group of something that corresponds to another table I believe. I'm trying to return a list of products that do not have a relationship to a specific customer.

Comment: Yes I know but it can lead you to solution as stated by @lazyberezovsky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return all products, which do not have related record in purchases table.

```
int customerID = 1;
var query = from ap in context.TB_AvailableProducts
            join p in context.TB_Purchases.Where(x => x.Cust_ID == customerID) 
                 on ap.Prod_ID equals p.Prod_ID into g
            where !g.Any()
            select ap;
```

I don't think you need `Distinct` here if you don't have duplicated records in your products table.

Generated SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT ap.Prod_ID, ap.Name
FROM TB_AvailableProducts AS ap
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS C1
    FROM TB_Purchases AS p
    WHERE (1 = p.Cust_ID) AND (ap.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @lazyberezovsky, however when I tried it, it does not work. Its returning nothing when there should be a decent sized list here.

Comment: This query returns all products, which does not have records in purchases table. Maybe I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you clarify your expectations?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of products that a specific customer has never purchased.